# Allow very long "from .." imports for black in order to stick to max line length?

Tags: python, lint, python-black

In our projects instead of using relative imports, we usually create the code as python packages and install them with `pip install -e .` This is nice and prevents from issues with import errors on different machines/IDEs.
However, for bigger project with a deeper structure this however means quite long import statements, which is where problem with black starts. E.G the following (dummy) example import

```
from root.machine_vision.hardware_layer.cameras.some_camera_brand. \
    camera_access_class import CameraAccessClass
```

would be changed by black into

```
from root.machine_vision.hardware_layer.cameras.some_camera_brand.camera_access_class import (
    CameraAccessClass
)
```

Which would cause issues with the max. line length.
So far I have only found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72717617/7745011), which suggests to turn black off for the block in question with `# fmt: off` and `# fmt: on`. I'm wondering if it is possible to tell black to allow backslashes in these kind of imports.

On the other hand, is there maybe another way to handle such long imports? For example some way to do "part imports", which would look something like

```
import root.machine_vision.hardware_layer as hwl
from hwl.cameras.some_camera_brand.camera_access_class import CameraAccessClass
```

So far I have not found a satisfactory solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the surface similarities, there is a distinct difference between a fully qualified module name like `root.machine_vesion.hardware_layer.cameras` and an *expression* like `hwl.cameras`. `hwl` is a variable that refers to a particular package, not the name of that package, and whether that package has an attribute named `cameras` is determined by the package itself.

Assuming the package `root.machine_version.hardware_layers` does exposes `cameras` as an attribute, (and each lower package exposes the necessary module as an attribute as well) you could write

```
import root.machine_vision.hardware_layer as hwl
CameraAccessClass = hwl.cameras.some_camera_brand.camera_access_class.CameraAccessClass
```

---

The following

```
from hwl.cameras.some_camera_brand.camera_access_class import CameraAccessClass
```

would not work because the `import` statement requires a module name, not an expression that evaluates to a `module` object.